# IIS/VS2010 Web Deployment gives 404

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2010

I use 1 click publish to a few servers to deploy website from VS2010. All servers are running IIS7 under Windows 2008R2.

1 server is a bit special because it listens to port 80 but the firewall will map this to port 80 internally on that server.

Now I am trying to setup web publishing there too, but I always keep getting 404 from the publisher. I use these settings:
https://192.168.3.51:8172/msdeploy.axd
Site/application: DeployFrontend

The site is exactly the same as in IIS7.

I tried even switching to port 80 again but still no luck.

What could be wrong here? The logs don't give me anything either.

```
2011-07-22 12:13:45 192.168.3.51 POST /msdeploy.axd site=DeployFrontend 8172 - 192.168.3.50 - 404 7 0 15
```